Cannot get any response from HTTP API
I searched tutorials and library documentations which I already followed the sample codes using either Dio or Http. However, I don't know why I cannot get a response from calling the api. There is no error and any message allows me to debug. I read the logging from cloudwatch for the api gateway. There is no trigger. The app cannot be processed any more after calling the api as I use await for waiting for the response. How should I fix it?
  Future<void> makeGetRequest() async {
    try {
      const url =
          'https://918pynqzta.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getAllElderly';

      final uri = Uri.parse(url);

      final response = await http.get(uri);
      print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await makeGetRequest();
                        },)


I tried http and dio as well as postman.
From postman, I can successfully get the response of my lambda api.
I tried some common testing api in flutter app in my real device, e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, I can get the result successfully.
However, when I use my aws lambda api, it does not work. I check the logging of api gateway in Cloudwatch. There is no record of triggering the api gateway.

The print(response) statement may not display the response body directly, if you are expecting JSON data. For that reason
try this code for call get api with http
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future<void> makeGetRequest() async {
  try {
    const url = 'https://918pynqzta.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getAllElderly';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('Response body: $jsonResponse');
    } else {
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}


still cannot get the response

I am getting response. Please check your internet connection. Test in real device.

I have updated my answer with an explanation.

I tried http and dio as well as postman.
From postman, I can successfully get the response of my lambda api.
I tried some common testing api in flutter app in my real device, e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, I can get the result successfully.
However, when I use my aws lambda api, it does not work. I check the logging of api gateway in Cloudwatch. There is no record of triggering the api gateway.

I have printed API response in text... https://i.imgur.com/kQeMMSe.png,
Try to run app in another real device.

Thank you. I just found it works if I don't use debug mode.

You can use POSTMAN to check API response.
Also Flutter has Dio package for APIs.
dio api example
first import
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

Initialize dio
final dio = Dio();

use this code for getting api response.
void getHttp() async {
  final response = await dio.get('https://dart.dev');
  print(response);
}


I tried http and dio as well as postman.
From postman, I can successfully get the response of my lambda api.
I tried some common testing api in flutter app in my real device, e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, I can get the result successfully.
However, when I use my aws lambda api, it does not work. I check the logging of api gateway in Cloudwatch. There is no record of triggering the api gateway.
